# What does the 'potential' rating do in DexNav search?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Pokemon ORAS introduced the 'DexNav' search function, which allows you to sneak up on Pokemon, sometimes with unique abilities, unique moves and a higher level than you would find normally.

While sneaking up, you get a look at some of the aforementioned values, including a 'Potential' star rating, which appears to be out of 3.

What does the potential rating signify? it doesn't seem related to the moves/ability or other values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Potential" refers to the IV ([Individual Values](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values)) of the Pokemon.
Each star represents an IV with the max possible value (31).

[Source](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/dexnav.shtml)

Comment: So why 3 stars then? does that mean 3/6 IVs are maxed? or is it half a star per stat?

Comment: It would have to be very high average to have 3 stars (not all 6 maxed, that's close to impossible without RNG manipulation and/or excessive breeding). It would take a lot of research and testing to figure it out what the average is per star exactly, due to no way to tell exact IV's in game though. Eventually it will be figured out though, it will just take at least a few days, I guess.

Comment: @Robotnik I have seen information saying that each star represents one perfect (max) IV, but until I find more proof I'm not gonna put it in my answer.

Comment: Since serebii now has the information on dexnav, I updated my answer.

Comment: This is true, I caught a bunch of Unown and I got one with better HP and Attack IVs than the others.

Answer (score 2):

The official strat guide says that each star represents one perfect IV. So 3 stars means it has at least 3 31 IVs.

[image: Picture from the official strategy guide]

Comment: What? 3 31 IVs? I thought it was 3 MAX IVs, because I caught an Unown with 108 HP.

Comment: @JDWhaler - IVs are a number ranging from 0 to 31 (i.e. 32 in total).

Answer (score 0):

The stars under potential represent a perfect and maxed IV of 31 for either HP, Attack, Defense, Spec. Attack, Spec. Defense or Speed.

In OR/AS it appears that any wild pokémon can have up to 3 perfect IV's. To get a pokémon with 6 perfect IV's on all stats, the player now seems to have to breed two wild pokémon with eachother.

Through this method, the player can have their offspring with 4 or more IV's of 31 breed with eachother, to increase the odds of eventually breeding a pokémon with 6 perfect IV's with a value of 31 each.

This puts emphasis on the importance of breeding, more so now that the IV rater (who tells you how many IV's of 31 your pokémon might have) and the breeding centre are cluttered together with an infinite road where you can drive circles to hatch the eggs that you breed.

Answer (score 0):

Each individual star represents a perfect IV. Its not really hard to find one with a perfect IV but to find one with 3 perfect IVs can be more difficult. but the DexNav gotchu. Just press on the pokemon (that you have seen in that area already) and press search and run around while your doing it (you dont have to run). I found an Adamant male synchrinize ralts with 3 perfect IVs and that was just a must have. Hopefully the two of the three perfect IVs will be on the attack and speed.