# What does the Dexnav Potential rating mean when there are no filled white stars?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I know about the DexNav and how [3 Stars means 3 IVs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192515/what-does-the-potential-rating-do-in-dexnav-search?rq=1), but I always encounter Pokémon with 3 Black stars and some with 1 white star and 2 black ones. What does it mean? The black stars and the white stars?

Answer (score 2):

If you run into a Pokemon with 3 Empty Stars (i.e. none of them are filled), this simply means that the Pokemon has **no** full IVs.

This is better than not seeing the potential rating at all, if you're specifically trying to get ones with IVs you can easily tell without starting a battle with it whether it'll be worth your time to catch it.

If a Pokemon has 1 star out of 3 filled, this just means that it has 1 max IV stat. The other 'unfilled' stars don't mean anything special in this case.